# Can somebody please explain to me how CCSpriteBatchNodes and spritesheets work ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I have built a little ipad game and spritesheets and batchnodes are all over the place. However I have no idea how they really work, when to add a sprite sheet, when to add sprites to the spritebatchnode etc. etc. .

This is what I do in the initial screen (main menu):

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet  = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprites.png"];
screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;    
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprites.plist"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];
```

In other classes - I always need to use the same batch node -> "sprites.png" - I call

```
CCSprite *someSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:someSpriteFrameName.png];
```

and add it to `self`.

```
[self addChild:someSprite]; // I do not understand why I would add my sprite to the batch node instead of self
```

So the situation is the following:

- I have 1 file called "sprites.png" where all my sprites are on.

  1. Do I make a new batch node whenever I change the scene ? The spriteframecache should stay   the same right ?
  2. What would I have to do with the spriteframecache if i had two sprite sheet files ?
  3. When do I add children to the batch node, and why ?

I really don't seem to grasp the concept entirely. I know approximately why I use it. But I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain everything to me again in layman terms, so I am 100% sure about what I do. Please try to explain it as basic as it gets.

- Thank you very much -
      Martin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. CCSpriteBatchNode is CCNode successor so you have to create separate instance for every scene. You can use several batch nodes on the scene if you have more than one texture file.

   `CCSpriteFrameCache` is a singleton so it stays the same during application lifetime.
2. Add both to `CCSpriteFrameCache`. `CCSpriteFrameCache` singleton has `loadedFilenames_` field (instance of `NSMutableSet`) which caches all sprite frames for all scenes.
3. You have to use batch node when you expect large amount of sprites with similar textures. For example you want to generate 100 coins every 2 seconds. If you use usual `CCNode` and create sprites on it, your application will allocate these 100 `CCSprite` objects every 2 seconds. `CCSpriteBatchNode` is targeted for performance and better memory usage. It works like `UITableView` with reusable cells.

   When you scroll table view with reusable cells, it does not create new cells. When new cell has to be presented on screen table view simply finds cell with same reuse identifier offscreen and replaces it's content with new content. `CCSpriteBatchNode` works in the same way. When you try to add new sprite to it, the node tries to find unused sprite offscreen and replaces it's content.

   Remember that sprites which you add to `CCSpriteBatchNode` have to use the textures from texture file which was used to create this batch node.

   Following example is based on code from your question:

```c
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode  = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprites.png"];
screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;    
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprites.plist"];
[self addChild:batchNode];
CCSprite *someSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"someSpriteFrom_sprites.png_.png];
[batchNode addChild:someSprite]; // add sprite to batch node to get all advantages of it
```

Here is a good article about CCSpriteBatchNode performance: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/

Comment: okay thank you. Very well explained! What if, say, my menu (where I set the spriteframe(swithfile) in my singleton is called more than once ? is it going to add a new entry or is it going to handle duplicate entries ?

Comment: and what if I want to add another sprite with the same texture ? Do I just call `CCSprite *someSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"someSpriteFrom_sprites.png_.png];
[batchNode addChild:someSprite];` again ? I ask this because then I would add another sprite to a node anyway, which would probably result in a `-draw` call which is equally expensive. Or am I getting something wrong here ?

Comment: Feel free to add as many sprites as you need. Batch node is optimised to handle such cases. In my case (I'm working on game now) I have two batch nodes and several independent sprites on screen moving rather rapidly. Default log shown by cocos2d informs that I have only 17 sprites on-screen simultaneously and FPS is 60 (I thingk it's good result).

Comment: Oh perfect thank you :). What are you developing on ? (iPad/iPad2/iPad3/iPhone4[S]/3G[S]?) My framerate is pretty much constant at 60 as well, so I cannot complain about that either. I'd recommend you "developing" for the iPhone5 in advance as far as graphics are concerned, which is what I am going to do with my game. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: We support all devices capable to run iOS >= 4.3 (so they are iPhone 3GS/4/4S and all iPads).

If you have 60 FPS — it means that everything is OK!

Comment: very cool ! can you show me some of your works ? Are they in the iTunes store already ?

Comment: Project which uses cocos2d is still in development. Previous project was created using Corona SDK: http://thevixes.com

Answer (score 0):

**Modern renderer**
We rewrote the renderer from scratch. The Render graph was decoupled from the Scene graph.
That means that auto-batching is supported, finally :-) And the new renderer is so fast, that we no longer encourage the use of SpriteBatchNode.

Sprites have auto-culling too.

And the good thing is that we didn't sacrifice any of the old features: custom OpenGL commands are still supported!

[Refer this link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/216)

Hopes it helps